# Why I get a network error when sending a request in react with axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

As you see, I want to shorten my URL due to Cuttly API. Thus I send a request:

```js
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "https://cutt.ly/api/api.php",
      headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
      params: {
        key: "MY_KEY",
        short: this.state.inputText,
        name: ""
      }
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

But when send, I get a network error:

[image]

I used Cross-Origin header too, but my problem didn't solve.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: can you log err.response?

Comment: @Omar It's undefined.

Comment: what about err.message?

Comment: @Omar Network Error

Comment: @Omar My internet is OK, Cuttly works like a charm and also I've added allow origin. There is no other reasons.

Comment: Look at the chrome network tab and analyze the response and any errors there.

Comment: @AndyRay In the status writes CORS error. Type: XHR.

Comment: @AndyRay But I've added this ```headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }```

Comment: CORS rules are defined by the *server*. If the client could control CORS it would be pointless.

Comment: @DaveNewton So, it's not my fault?